# Override Prestashop setMedia function to put js and css files at the bottom

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I have well known FrontController override

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {

   public function setMedia()
    {
      parent::setMedia();   
      $this->addJS(array(
        _THEME_JS_DIR_.'adds.js'
       ));  
    }
}
```

This wokrks as expected but with one issue -> adds this new js/css files at the top of the included files list, like here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/adds.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/default-bootstrap/js/global.js"></script>
```

And this is bad because my script land above jquery's script..

**How to make it like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/default-bootstrap/js/global.js?version=2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/adds.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand why your script tag links to `/js/adds.js` while you're using `_THEME_JS_DIR_.'adds.js'`. It should be linking to `/themes/default-bootstrap/js/adds.js`. Is this really what you get or did you changed your script before posting it here?

Comment: The main purpose is good. How to change position of the overrided js/css files to land at the bottom of the loaded js/css files. I have done it in quite better way

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple custom module (50 lines) with hookHeader function like below. Works like a charm!

```
public function hookHeader($params)
     {
         $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/adds.css', 'all');
         $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/adds.js', 'all');

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use *addJquery()* before *addJS()* to get jQuery added before, for example:

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJquery();
    $this->context->controller->addJS(Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/my.js');
}
```

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+jQuery+and+jQueryUI